# How to remove extraneous page numbers from ePub TOC

Tags: epub, table-of-contents, indesign

I've created this [epub file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yuzTrPmCK5h_AOrq3GtUamRSRKBJCnAe/view?usp=sharing) as an export from an Indesign file, and it's got two problems that I can see immediately:

1. The ToC includes page numbers after the chapter titles, even though I've created a special epub export ToC style in Indesign that isn't supposed to include the page numbers of references (see [image: screenshot].

Note that in the ePub export dialogue, I made sure to set my special ToC style like this:

[image: this]

Yet the ToC in the ePub when viewed on Apple books still has the page numbers there -- like this:

[image: this]

How do I get rid of the page numbers that appear after the chapter titles?

2. The title pages aren't carrying over the Playfair Display font from the print PDF of the book, and there's a page break on the dedication page. How do I fix this?

Thank you so much if anyone can help!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you can persuade InDesign to export this correctly, but if this is a one-off and you don't need to do many like it, it would very probably be easier to open it in [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/) (free), edit the ToC, and use Calibre to re-pack the ePub. Alternately, you can unzip the ePub, edit the ToC file in a text editor, and re-zip it in this order -- OSX, but I think the flags work on Linux and maybe Win:

```
prompt$ zip -X0 title.epub mimetype
prompt$ zip -Xr "title.epub" "META-INF/" "OEBPS/"
```

Answer (score 0):

InDesign 2022 has an option when creating TOC in InDesign to remove numbers. There are two places to adjust this in the TOC creating dialogue box, click "advanced" settings.